# Restrict clients to use only one configuration from list of configurations created from yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

In my Spring Boot app I have **application.yml** configuration file with following content

```
config:
gateways:
    -
        id: 'g0'
        nbrInputs: 128
        nbrOutputs: 128
    -
        id: 'g1'
        nbrInputs: 128
        nbrOutputs: 128
```

Configuration Class:

```
 @Configuration
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config")
 @EnableConfigurationProperties
 public class GatewayConfig
 {
     List<Gateway> gateways = new ArrayList<Gateway>();

     public List<Gateway> getGatewayList(){
          return gateways;
     }

     public static class Gateway
     {
       private String id;
       private int nbrInputs;
       private int nbrOutputs;

       // Getters and Setters
       // ...
      }
 }
```

I want to expose these gateways to client but want to allow one gateway to get used with only one client class(clientA or clientB).

For that, I have writtean a Mapper class to map client implementations to gateways based on the id provided by them.

```
@Component
public class MapGatewaytoClasses{
     @Autowired
     private GatewayConfig gc;

     @Autowired
     private ApplicationContext ac;

     @PostConstruct
     public void init(){
          List<Gateway> lg = gc.getGatewayList();
          Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Myannotation.class);

          for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : beans.entrySet()) {
               for(Gateway g: lg){
                   Client c = (Client)entry.getValue();
                    if(c.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(g.getId())){
                            c.setGateway(g);
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}

public abstract client{
    protected String id;
    public String getId() {
       return id;
    }
}
```

Now the new clients will have to extend this Client to use.

```
@Component
@Myannotation
public class clientA extends Client {         
     Gateway gateway;
     public A(){
         id="g0";
     }
     public void setGateway(Gateway gateway){
         this.gateway = gateway;
     }
}

@Component
@Myannotation
public class clientB extends Client{
     Gateway gateway;
     public B(){
         id="g1";
     }

     public void setGateway(Gateway gateway){
         this.gateway = gateway;
     }
}
```

**How should I restrict clientA and clientB to not use the same gateway id.**
They are allowed to use any gateways but they should not use the same gateway.
Or **is there any other better way to map clientA or clientB with gateways**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At compile time, clients of these classes cannot know if the an id/gateway is already used.
It can be discovered only at runtime when you associate gateways to client objects :

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void init(){
      List<Gateway> lg = gc.getGatewayList();
      Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Myannotation.class);

      for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : beans.entrySet()) {
           for(Gateway g: lg){
               Client c = (Client)entry.getValue();
                if(c.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(g.getId())){
                        c.setGateway(g);
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

At this time, it is too late. So as workaround you can just disable or reallocate a new gateway for clients that declares the same gateway id.

> Is there any other better way to map clientA or clientB with gateways

Yes a way where clients are not directly coupled to a a gateway 
but instead where the server associates clients to the gateways what matches their requirement.
The idea is providing a pool of gateways in the server side.
From the client side, clients don't specify which exactly gateway they will use, instead they specify only theirs requirements about the gateway capacities that they need, that is all but the gateway id :

```
config:

gateways:
    -
        id: 'g0'
        nbrInputs: 128
        nbrOutputs: 128
    -
        id: 'g1'
        nbrInputs: 64
        nbrOutputs: 64

client-gateway:
    -
        nbrInputs: 128
        nbrOutputs: 128
    -
        nbrInputs: 64
        nbrOutputs: 64
```

It would be the role of the server to allocate at runtime a gateway for each declared client that requires that. 
It should be probably be done in the `init()` method.
Here is a example to give an idea :

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void init(){
     Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Myannotation.class);

     for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : beans.entrySet()) {
               Client c = (Client) entry.getValue();
               Optional<Gateway> gateway = findMatchingGateway(c);
               if (gateway.isPresent()){
                     c.setGateway(g);
                     gc.getGatewayList()
                       .removeIf(o->o.getId()==g.getId())
               )
               else {
                     // handle the not found case
               }


           }
     }
 } 


private Optional<Gateway> findMatchingGateway(Client client){
    return 
      gc.getGatewayList()
        .stream()
        .filter(g.nbrInputs() == client.getNbrInputs())
        .findAny();
}
```